# conditional display php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php echo $row['time']; ?>&nbsp;Normal time (<?php echo $row['time']/2; ?> years)
```

I want to have a case when ['time']/2 > 1 it is shown as years but if it is 1 it shall be shown only as year

How can I do this using if else

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to show "year" if $row['time']/2 is 1 (0 is still plural), so you want to do something like:

```
   <? $years = $row['time'] / 2; ?>
   <?= $row['time'] ?> Semester (<?= $years == 1 ? '1 year' : $years.' years' ?>)
```

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $years = $row['time']/2; ?>
<?php echo $row['time']; ?>&nbsp;Semster (<?php echo $years > 1 ? $years.' years' : $years.' year'; ?>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $row['time']; ?>&nbsp;Semster (<?php echo $row['time']/2; ?> year<?php if( $row['time']/2 > 1 ): ?>s<?php endif; ?>)
```

Leave off the `s` and only add it if `time/2 > 1`